# Multithreading random number and CPU monitoring

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Im a noob and im dipping my toes into multithreading.

I wanted to write a python3 script that is using multithreading, generating CPU load on each core and then measure the load and log it.

I wrote a small script that is taking a random generated number from the NIST randomness beacon and is using it as a seed to generate a "random" number.

I run four copies of the same function on four different threads and I have a fifth thread that is running a linux command to log the cpu activity. Each function has a boolean so that after the function is done with its work it will flip that switch so that the monitoring (cpu log) function will stop logging when all functions are done.

data.out is being created but only has one random number instead of the 100 that should be there because of the for loop and the cpu.log is not being created.

Im not sure where I messed up.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import array as arr
import numpy as np
import random
import re
import os

t1 = False
t2 = False
t3 = False
t4 = False

def get_NIST_SEED():
    url = 'https://beacon.nist.gov/beacon/2.0/pulse/last'
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data_set = str(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
    subStr = data_set
    subStr = re.findall(r'"outputValue" : "(.+?)"',data_set)
    subStr  = ''.join(subStr)
    NIST_SEED = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, subStr))
    NIST_SEED = float(NIST_SEED)
    return NIST_SEED

def set_array():
    numbers = arr.array('d', [])
    return numbers


def generate_number(NIST_SEED, numbers):
    i = 0
    random_number = random.seed(NIST_SEED)
    for i in range(100):
        random_number = random.random()
        numbers.extend([random_number])
        np.savetxt('data.out', numbers)
        return numbers

def monitoring():
    while t1 and t2 and t3 and t4 is False:
        os.system("mpstat -u >> cpu.log")

def nist_1():
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    t1 = True

def nist_2():
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    t2 = True

def nist_3():
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    t3 = True

def nist_4():
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    t4 = True

def Main():
    p1 = Process(target=nist_1, args=())
    p2 = Process(target=nist_2, args=())
    p3 = Process(target=nist_3, args=())
    p4 = Process(target=nist_4, args=())
    p5 = Process(target=monitoring, args=())

    p5.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p5.join()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

for x in range(0,1):
    Main()
os.system("cat cpu.log")
```

the generator works and is creating n number of random numbers depending on the range:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import array as arr
import random
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://beacon.nist.gov/beacon/2.0/pulse/last'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data_set = str(f.read().decode('utf-8'))


subStr = data_set


subStr = re.findall(r'"outputValue" : "(.+?)"',data_set)
subStr  = ''.join(subStr)
NIST_SEED = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, subStr))
NIST_SEED = float(NIST_SEED)

numbers = arr.array('d', [])

i = 0

random_number = random.seed(NIST_SEED)
for i in range(10):
    random_number = random.random()
    numbers.extend([random_number])

np.savetxt('data.out', numbers)

os.system("cat data.out")
```

(EDIT) - Here is my attempt to do a multithread multicore version:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import array as arr
import numpy as np
import random
import re
import os

def NIST_THREAD_CORE():
    t1 = True
    t2 = True
    t3 = True
    t4 = True

    def get_NIST_SEED():
        return random.random()

    def set_array():
        numbers = arr.array('d', [])
        return numbers


    def generate_number(NIST_SEED, numbers):
        i = 0
        random_number = random.seed(NIST_SEED)
        for i in range(100):
            random_number = random.random()
            numbers.extend([random_number])
            np.savetxt('data.out', numbers)
            return numbers

    def monitoring():
        print("In monitoring")
        while t1 or t2 or t3 or t4:
            os.system("mpstat -u >> cpu.log")

    def nist_1():
        print ("nist_1 begin")
        returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
        array = set_array()
        generate_number(returned_string,array)
        global t1
        t1 = False
        print ("nist_1 end")

    def nist_2():
        print ("nist_2 begin")
        returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
        array = set_array()
        generate_number(returned_string,array)
        global t2
        t2 = False
        print ("nist_2 end")

    def nist_3():
        print ("nist_3 begin")
        returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
        array = set_array()
        generate_number(returned_string,array)
        global t3
        t3 = False
        print ("nist_3 end")

    def nist_4():
        print ("nist_4 begin")
        returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
        array = set_array()
        generate_number(returned_string,array)
        global t4
        t4 = False

    def Main():
        p1 = threading.Thread(target=nist_1, args=())
        p2 = threading.Thread(target=nist_2, args=())
        p3 = threading.Thread(target=nist_3, args=())
        p4 = threading.Thread(target=nist_4, args=())
        p5 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=())

        p5.start()
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p3.start()
        p4.start()

        p5.join()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        p3.join()
        p4.join()

    for x in range(0,1):
        Main()
        os.system("cat cpu.log")

NIST_THREAD_CORE()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()

    processes = [Process(NIST_THREAD_CORE())]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Do you want `multithreading` or `multiprocessing`? They are very different under Python.

Comment: Id like to do both!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. First of all you are using process (internally every process will have at least one thread) than threads ( 1 process and multiple threads). Processes will behave differently based on your current cpu load. What you could do is print start and end of each function to see if p5 was indeed started before others.

The main problem is with your while condition

```
while t1 and t2 and t3 and t4 is False:
```

t1 is already false so while loop will never execute. Your condition is checking if all are true and t4 is only False.

I would initialize t1,t2,t3,t4 to True and set it to False once its done.

and while condition to

```
while t1 or t2 or t3 or t4:
```

or with your existing code

```
while t1 is False or t2 is False or t3 is False or t4 is False:
```

As you might want to output till any of the process is running or if you want to stop logging if any one of them is done than "and"

Comment: Another way to test is while t1 is False and t2 is False and so on with your existing code.

Comment: I tried to set t1, t2, t3 and t4 so that the logging will only stop when all threads are done. I tried your last suggestion and the scripts doesn't finish at all. It seems to keep running and I have to cancel out.

Comment: My mistake I forgot that you are creating processes and the global variable updates will not be directly visible to main process. Once you create a process a new context is created for that process and setting the variable True/False will not be visible to another process.

Comment: Checkout my latest answer. For process you have to do a different way too much to write here. You should read about interprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

Using threads and setting the variable as global so that it reflects in other threads. I have also changed to seed for simplicity

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import array as arr
import numpy as np
import random
import re
import os

t1 = True
t2 = True
t3 = True
t4 = True

def get_NIST_SEED():
    return random.random()

def set_array():
    numbers = arr.array('d', [])
    return numbers


def generate_number(NIST_SEED, numbers):
    i = 0
    random_number = random.seed(NIST_SEED)
    for i in range(100):
        random_number = random.random()
        numbers.extend([random_number])
        np.savetxt('data.out', numbers)
        return numbers

def monitoring():
    print("In monitoring")
    while t1 or t2 or t3 or t4:
        os.system("mpstat -u >> cpu.log")

def nist_1():
    print ("nist_1 begin")
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    global t1
    t1 = False
    print ("nist_1 end")

def nist_2():
    print ("nist_2 begin")
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    global t2
    t2 = False
    print ("nist_2 end")

def nist_3():
    print ("nist_3 begin")
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    global t3
    t3 = False
    print ("nist_3 end")

def nist_4():
    print ("nist_4 begin")
    returned_string = get_NIST_SEED()
    array = set_array()
    generate_number(returned_string,array)
    global t4
    t4 = False
def Main():
    #p1 = Process(target=nist_1, args=())
    #p2 = Process(target=nist_2, args=())
    #p3 = Process(target=nist_3, args=())
    #p4 = Process(target=nist_4, args=())
    #p5 = Process(target=monitoring, args=())
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=nist_1, args=())
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=nist_2, args=())
    p3 = threading.Thread(target=nist_3, args=())
    p4 = threading.Thread(target=nist_4, args=())
    p5 = threading.Thread(target=monitoring, args=())

    p5.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p5.join()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

for x in range(0,1):
    Main()
os.system("cat cpu.log")
```

Sample output

```
In monitoring
 nist_1 begin
nist_2 begin
nist_3 begin
nist_4 begin
nist_1 end
nist_2 end
nist_3 end
nist_4 end
Linux 2.6.32-754.19.1.el6.x86_64 (njsdlpagtslx7)        01/22/2020      _x86_64_        (16 CPU)

10:41:19 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:41:19 AM  all   32.93    0.00    1.49    0.86    0.00    0.11    0.00    0.00   64.61
Linux 2.6.32-754.19.1.el6.x86_64 (njsdlpagtslx7)        01/22/2020      _x86_64_        (16 CPU)

10:41:19 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
10:41:19 AM  all   32.93    0.00    1.49    0.86    0.00    0.11    0.00    0.00   64.61
```